# The symbolic link is overriding the environment variable in linux

Tags: linux, centos6

I have installed Java using rpm on Centos 6 and set the JAVA_HOME in .bash_profile file. However the java -version was printing the version of some other Java installation which was installed earlier. It did not effective even after restart. On further investigation I found that there was a symbolic link 
**/usr/bin/java** which is pointing to the other version. I had to delete it and create a new one pointing to the new installation for it work.

Is this normal to have this symbolic link created on installation or it might be created by some one manually? Also is the symbolic link has higher precedence than the environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

CentOS

---

The links /usr/bin/{ java, javac } are created with the /etc/alternatives/ mechanism.

HOWTO install a new version to /etc/alternatives/ , example :

```
# /usr/sbin/alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_66/bin/java 2000
```

... Please enter your actual path, if not /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_66/bin/java .

---

HOWTO select a java version ( Which will create the right link(s))

```
# /usr/sbin/alternatives --config java
```

---